# How to send corresponding var to second php page without form or into url?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two php page.I'm using Bootstrap, php and mysql. In the first page I load three objects into div from mysql database of the user logged. To do this I'm using the next code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<?php 
require_once('function.php');
conectar('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');

$consulta1 = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM user WHERE username="'.$_SESSION["name"].'"'); 

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM finc WHERE Usuario_idUsuario="'.$_SESSION["idUser"].'"'); 
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    do{
        echo '<div class="col-lg-4">' ;
  echo '<img class="center-block img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhOw=="
      alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">';
      echo '<h2 class="text-center">'.$row['name'].'</h2>';
      echo '<p align="center">'.$row['data'].'</p>';
      echo '<p align="center">'.$row['tao'].'</p>';
      echo '
        <a  type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="secondPage.php" role="button">Entrar »</a>
        ';
        echo'</div>';
        }while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
} else { 
 echo "¡ No data for this user!"; 
 <a} 

        ?>
    <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

I need send the id value depending of the button clicked for load the data associated in the next php page. For example, If I click in the second button created in the do-while loop I need send the id=2 to the sencondPage.php. I have searched how to do this, but only find how to send var into url like sencondPage.php?var=2, And I hate this because user can change url... And adding value into session, but on click I haven't get this.

So, how can I pass the corresponding id value when user click in the link??

Thanks!

Comment: you HAVE to have the id sent client->server SOMEHOW, otherwise there's no way for the server to know which row was clicked. there's not much point in hiding that url (e.g. using an ajax request), because a knowledgeable user can simply get it from the browser's debug console anyways.

Comment: No matter what you do a user can manipulate it. You either need to submit the var via GET or POST or put it in a cookie with javascript. All three of those options are editable by the end user.

Comment: The reason to not send data using GET is that if modifying the url causes a data mutation on the server then bad things can happen when a user refreshes the page.  I also happen to think `?` in urls is a bit ugly.  It's true that you can't prevent a savvy user from changing what they send to the server but you can effect what a typical user sees and there are good reasons to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an html `<form>`:

```
<form method="post" action="[URL FOR NEXT PAGE]">
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="value1" value="Button 1" />
  <input type="submit" name="value2" value="Button 2" />
</form>
```

Now if someone clicks the first button it will send them to the next page with the post data: `value1=Button%201`, and if they click the second button the it will instead be `value2=Button%202`.  In either case any other form elements inside the form will also be submitted via post.  With PHP you can retrieve these values using something like:

```
if ($_POST['value1']) {
  ...
elseif ($_POST['value2']) {
  ...
}
```